# How to develop system barcode in asp classic?

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner

Can someone know about barcode scanner in asp classic? I'm newbie in this program. Before this project I know develop with programming asp classic but not for barcode system.

I hope someone can help me, about tutorial or sample code for beginner to develop barcode system in asp classic.

Answer (score 1):

Classic ASP is server-side. You can't integrate with local hardware (i.e. barcode scanners on client machines)

If you want to read barcode images, for example, photos uploaded via a browser to a web-server try the BytesCout BarCode Reader:

https://bytescout.com/products/developer/barcodereadersdk/bytescoutbarcodereadersdk_first_step_with_asp_classic.html

Comment: yes, bytescout barcode reader sdk works great with classic ASP. But you need to have .NET 2 or .NET 4 installed on the server to get it to work as the sdk's core engine runs on .net